# How to refresh a label without reloading the page

Tags: c#, .net, refresh, page-refresh

I want to refresh a label on a page without reloading the page.

The page is used to send SMSs. Because I am using a GSM modem connected to a COM port, it is quite a slow process taking about 3 seconds per text. (There's a lengthy reason why I'm using a serial GSM modem, not an online service or USB connection.)

Multiple numbers can be specified, delimited by `";"`. I want to update the page as soon as each text is sent; but at the moment it just updates the label all in one go at the end. What's the simplest way to achieve this? Thoughts were maybe AJAX, JavaScript or Threading. (As I say, simple is good!)

**Current code:**

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM1", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        try
        {
            String[] numbers = tbNo.Text.Split(';');


            foreach (string n in numbers)
            {

                sp.Open();

                sp.Write("AT+CMGF=1" + (char)(13));

                Thread.Sleep(200);

                sp.Write("AT+CMGS=" + n.Replace(" ", string.Empty) + (char)(13));

                Thread.Sleep(200);

                sp.Write(tbMsg.Text + (char)(13) + (char)(26));

                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                sp.Close();

                Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "Message sent to " + n + "<br />";

            }

        } catch (Exception error) {

            Label1.Text = error.Message;
        };
```

Comment: Ajax, which *is* Javascript. (It is what the j stands for)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a service on server side if you have ASP.net, it can be a WCF Rest service, send a post request to server as ajax call and upon receiving the result change the `label text` in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to use some AJAX for this. One way that's actually quite easy to implement is to use [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR).

SignalR is a framework that supports a realtime connection between the client and the server. This makes your code a lot easier. If you don't use SignalR you would have to manually implement something like polling (where the client browser asks the server every X seconds what the status of your task is) or some variation on this.

SignalR hides the underlying mechanism used and creates a connection between the server and client.

Your code on the server would look something like this:

```
public class SmsHub : Hub
{
   public Task SendMessages(string input)
   {
      // ... send sms message

     Caller.updateStatus('Message send!');
   }
}
```

And on your client you would use the javascript hub to send and receive messages. The `updateStatus` function can append a HTML message to some information div.

This is a nice [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) by Scott Hanselman that can also help you getting started.